# Is there a chance for a new university in another country to accept my passed courses/classes?

Tags: university, transfer-student

I'm looking to transfer to another university in another country - University of Geneva.

Is there a chance that they will accept my passed classes in homeland university as all/most of my classes are the same with the one I'm willing to transfer?

I'm looking to finish the last year in University of Geneva.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you currently studying?

Comment: I'm studying Computer Sciences in Serbia and that's what I'm looking for to continue in Geneva as most the classes are the same.

Comment: @astronaut was asking you _where_? Not what are you studying.

Comment: While we can speculate about this, you should really ask the University of Geneva.

Answer (score 2):

Many universities/countries in europe have adopted the "bologna system" which mainly aims for comparability of degrees so that it gets easy to do masters studies in a different country than your bachelor. With this they also adopted the ECTS (European Credit Transfer System) which should make different courses comparable. There are definitely ambitions to make it possible to switch mid studies.

So much for theory. In the real world, at least here in Austria, it is definitely possible to finish your study at another university. However, they might not accept all your finished courses or not with that amount of credits. We even had cases where master/PhD students were required to do bachelor studies lab courses to get to a similar level.

All of this is usually handeled by the dean of studies who can decide if you are allowed to finish your studies at that university and what you have to do to reach that goal. What you should do is speak to the dean and ask them directly, only he/she can give you an answer if it works in your case.